# Getting 502 Bad Gateway Error on POST via ngrok

Tags: flask, ngrok

I'm using pythonanywhere to receive texts via Twilio, and everytime I send a text back (POST request) I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway Error. See below for my code.

```
import requests
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from pytz import timezone
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio import twiml


app = Flask(__name__)


proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient(proxy={'http': os.environ['http_proxy'], 'https': os.environ['https_proxy']})
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token,http_client=proxy_client)

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms():
    print('test')
    number = request.form['From']
    message_body = request.form['Body']
    resp = twiml.Response()
    resp.message("hi")
    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this is the error I'm getting[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ2W2.png)

Comment: There are a number of things that can cause 502s. There is a help page in the PythonAnywhere help pages that covers how to start diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you are asking Flask to retrieve content from the body as `multipart/form-data` that may not exist.

Try changing `request.form['From']` to `request.form.get('From')` which will not raise a `KeyError` if the key is missing.

Another option is to wrap your function (temporarily) into a `try/except` block and print out the traceback so you can at least find out what is happening on the server from `stdout` and debug the issue that way.